# perl optional command line argument

Tags: perl, command-line, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I am new to Perl and wish to know if the following logic works in Perl :-

I have to execute a command using Perl script with some arguments and I need to prepare that
arguments list, some of the arguments are also optional ( may or may not present)

```
push(@args, $arguments[0]);
push(@args, @controller);
push(@args, @member);
```

Out of the above arguments I have arguments[0] that is required and controller and member are optional. My doubt is in case "controller" argument is not present do I need to put "null"
there or by default Perl will take care of it ?

Edit:- 
To clarify the question I don't have the "controller" argument but have the "member" argument.

Thanks
-Arpit

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a hash as the only argument? e.g. `%hash = {agr0 => $arguments[0], ctrl => @controller, mem => @member}`

Comment: @YoannCouble Your code is broken - either use `%hash = ( ... )` or `$hash_ref = { ... }`

Comment: @Xaerxess Ooops, right, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to a subroutine are passed in an array. It looks like you already realise that as you're building up your arguments in `@args`.

If your subroutine is just expecting a list of arguments of arguments, then there are some problems with your approach.

Firstly, as you've realised, if you push an empty array onto an array, you will get no items added on to your `@args` array. And that's going to confuse your subroutine. It's simple enough to test this using Data::Dumper.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

my @arguments = ('Arg1');
my @controller;
my @member;
my @args;

push(@args, $arguments[0]);
push(@args, @controller);
push(@args, @member);

say Dumper \@args;
```

The output looks like this:

```
$ ./args 
$VAR1 = [
          'Arg1'
        ];
```

But you also have the opposite problem. If `@controller` or `@member` contain more than one element, then your argument array gets messed up by having too much in it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

my @arguments = ('Arg1');
my @controller = ('C1', 'C2');
my @member = ('M1', 'M2');
my @args;

push(@args, $arguments[0]);
push(@args, @controller);
push(@args, @member);

say Dumper \@args;
```

Which gives:

```
$ ./args2
$VAR1 = [
          'Arg1',
          'C1',
          'C2',
          'M1',
          'M2'
        ];
```

The solution to both of these problems is the same. If you want exactly one element from `@controller` and `@member`, then ask for exaclty one element. If there are too few, then you'll get an `undef` in the array and if there are too many, then you'll get the first.

Empty arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

my @arguments = ('Arg1');
my @controller;
my @member;
my @args;

push(@args, $arguments[0]);
push(@args, $controller[0]);
push(@args, $member[0]);

say Dumper \@args;
```

Which gives:

```
$ ./args3
$VAR1 = [
          'Arg1',
          undef,
          undef
        ];
```

Overfull arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

my @arguments = ('Arg1');
my @controller = ('C1', 'C2');
my @member = ('M1', 'M2');
my @args;

push(@args, $arguments[0]);
push(@args, $controller[0]);
push(@args, $member[0]);

say Dumper \@args;
```

Which gives:

```
$ ./args4
$VAR1 = [
          'Arg1',
          'C1',
          'M1'
        ];
```

Does that help?

Comment: +1: Showing OP how to test and figure out the answer for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Why are `@controller` and `@member` arrays?

Could you pass in more than one controller (if present)? Or, did you think that both arguments to `push` must be arrays?

The second argument can be a scalar value. Test before you push:

```
push(@args, $arguments[0]);
push(@args, $controller) if defined $controller;
push(@args, $member)     if defined $member;
```

This will push in blank/null strings, but not if the arguments are undefined. If you don't want these if these values have blank or null or zero values, you could do this:

```
push(@args, $arguments[0]);
push(@args, $controller) if $controller;
push(@args, $member)     if defined $member;
```

And, you can use `join` to rejoin your arguments back into a single string:

```
my $full_command = join " ", $command, @args;

my $errors = system qw($full_command);
```

Or, if you don't need the shell for execution:

```
my $errors = system $command, @args;
```

This will execute your command without the shell.